# Boolean always true

Tags: java

here is the first class :

```
package Chatter;



 public class Timer
{

private long period;
private long start;
private long CurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

public Timer(long period)
{
    this.period = period;
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public long getElapsed()
{
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
}

public long getRemaining()
{
    return period - getElapsed();
}

public boolean isRunning()
{
    return getElapsed() <= period;
}

public long TimetoExcucte(int Seconds){
    return CurrentTime + (Seconds * 1000);
}

public boolean Reached(int Seconds){
    return System.currentTimeMillis() > TimetoExcucte(Seconds);
    keyboard.typeString("Test", true);
}

public void reset()
{
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public void stop()
{
    period = 0;
}

public static String format(long milliSeconds)
{
    long secs = milliSeconds / 1000L;
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", new Object[] {
        Long.valueOf(secs / 3600L), Long.valueOf((secs % 3600L) / 60L), Long.valueOf(secs % 60L)
    });
}
}
```

and here is the second class:

```
    package Chatter;

import java.util.List;
import Chatter.Timer;


import org.osbot.rs07.api.ui.Message;
import org.osbot.rs07.script.Script;

import org.osbot.rs07.script.ScriptManifest;




@ScriptManifest(name="Chatter", author="Chatter", version=1, info="Chatter", logo="")
public class Chatter extends Script{
private static long Lastime = 0;
private Dialogue Dialogue;
boolean said;
int Index;
Timer runTimer;

public void onStart() throws InterruptedException {
    runTimer = new Timer(0);

}

public int onLoop() throws InterruptedException {

    if(runTimer.Reached(5)){
        keyboard.typeString("Hoi", true);
    }else{
        log("Waiting");
    }

    return 500;
}

private void Respond() throws InterruptedException {
    //Message sending method
    if(said == true){
        sleep(random(2000,4500));
        Dialogue = new Dialogue();
        List<String> RespondSpeach = Dialogue.getNumberList1();
        keyboard.typeString(RespondSpeach.get(Index) , true);
        said = false;
    }
}

public void onMessage(Message m) throws InterruptedException {
    //Message recieveing method
    if(m.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        Dialogue = new Dialogue();
     List<String> ReceivedSpeach = Dialogue.getNumberList();
    for (String word : ReceivedSpeach){
        if (m.getMessage().contains(word)){
            Index = ReceivedSpeach.indexOf(word);
            said = true;
        }
    }
}

}
```

so the first class is the timer which act as it's name generate a timer and what i wanna do is make the script perform an action every 5seconds

this script runs on Osbot http://osbot.org/, and the action i wanna perform is make the script write `Test` every 5 seconds but instead the script keeps spamming `Test`
how do i make the boolean work every 5 seconds instead of spamming?

Comment: Show your actual code. That code won't compile, so it's not the real code.

Comment: This code cannot compile. `keyboard.typeString("Test");` is not reachable.

Comment: Added the full class

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard.typeString is being called after the return call in the Reached function, which means it is never called. Try moving it to the right place.

Edited for a misunderstanding.

Comment: Both use milliseconds, in the first class the seconds is multiplied by 1000